# Please, can someone help me to create a trigger in mysql that has a same function with the assertion below?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, assertion

So basically I want to create a trigger for mysql database that has same/similar function with the assertion code below (since mysql does not support assertion)

Here is the assertion code that I want to replicate using trigger

```
CREATE ASSERTION assert
CHECK NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM paper P WHERE 3 <>(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM review R
    WHERE R.paperid = P.paperid)
);

CREATE ASSERTION atmostfivepapers
CHECK NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pcmember P WHERE 5 <
    ( SELECT *
    FROM review R
    WHERE R.email = P.email
    )
);
```

And here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE paper(
    paperid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    abstract VARCHAR(250),
    pdf VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(paperid)
);

CREATE TABLE author(
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    affiliation VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(email)
);

CREATE TABLE writePaper(
    paperid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    paper_order INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(paperid, email),
    FOREIGN KEY(paperid) REFERENCES paper(paperid),
    FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES author(email)
);

CREATE TABLE pcmember(
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(email)
);

CREATE TABLE review(
    reportid INT UNSIGNED,
    sdate DATE,
    comment VARCHAR(250),
    recommendation CHAR(1),
    paperid INT UNSIGNED,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(paperid, email),
    FOREIGN KEY(paperid) REFERENCES paper(paperid),
    FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES pcmember(email)
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you wanna create a trigger to duplicate your table?

Comment: yes, I want to duplicate it

Comment: just tell me the particular table you wanna duplicate and specify its attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create another table replicating the columns and their features. Thereafter create a trigger.

```
  CREATE TRIGGER afterInsert_trigger on yourMainTableName
  FOR INSERT
  AS
  INSERT INTO yourTableCopy(column1ofYourReplicateTable, column2OFyourReplicateTable, ... etc)
  SELECT column1ofYourMainTable, column2ofYourMainTable, ..., etc
  
  FROM INSERTED
```

That's what I use in Microsoft SQL server